# Why can I use kinematic equations for circular motion

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I am trying to understand why I can use the kinematic equations with circular motion. From my understanding I can only use the kinematic equations if the acceleration is constant but in circular motion the acceleration is not constant as the direction is always changing. The book I am using even states this but then goes on to use them and there is no explanation as to why I can use them.

Kinematic Equations:
$\omega_{f}=\omega_{i}+\alpha t$ 
$\omega_{f}^{2}=\omega_{i}^{2}+2\alpha\theta$
$\theta=\omega_{i}t + \frac{1}{2}\alpha t^{2}$

Comment: What equations are you referring to as the "kinematic equations"

Comment: In uniform circular motion the acceleration is constant.

Comment: @RC_23 I have added the kinematic equations I am referring to

Comment: These apply for constant angular acceleration for the same reason that the linear kinematic equations apply for constant linear acceleration.

Comment: If you want to know why this is mathematically valid, you can ask on Math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only looking at tangential motion, then if the tangential acceleration is constant you can use your constant acceleration equations to describe the motion.

It's kind of the same idea as if you had constant acceleration in the y-direction but varying acceleration in the x-direction. You can still use your constant acceleration equations for the motion in the y-direction, even though the overall acceleration vector is not constant. It's not a perfect analogy though.

Note this isn't true in general for motion described by polar coordinates, but it does fall out for circular motion where $\dot r=0$ and $\ddot r=0$.

Comment: I see, so even though the overall acceleration is not constant when I break it up into its radial and tangential components I can use the kinematic equations just for the tangential component. This is because they are independent of each other correct?

Comment: @mach123 the angular acceleration, a,  is constant if the rate of rotation is constant like an LP record turning. the tangential acceleration is just Ra. which is clearly constant if a is constant.

Comment: Refer to Kleppner and kolenkow

Comment: @mach123 Essentially yes. For circular motion you have $a_\theta=r\ddot\theta$. $r$ is constant, so if $a_\theta$ is constant then your constant acceleration equations just fall right out. In general the radial and tangential motions are not independent though (the acceleration components depend on more than just their respective position coordinates), so you should be careful in general, hence my note about the analogy not being perfect and my final sentence.

Answer (score 2):

*I am trying to understand why I can use the **kinematic** equations with circular motion.*

Dictionary definition, *kinematics* - the branch of mechanics concerned with the motion of objects without reference to the forces which cause the motion.

So are you asking about rotations in general or why the kinematic equations for rotation can be applied to a particular type of circular motion?

The four kinematic equations for linear motion are derived with the assumption that the **linear** acceleration, $\vec a$, is constant which means that its magnitude and direction do not change.

You start with the equation $\vec a=\dfrac{d\vec v}{dt} = a\,\hat s = \dfrac{d v\,\hat s}{dt} = \dfrac{d v}{dt} \,\hat s \Rightarrow a = \dfrac {dv}{dt}$.

The unit vector $\hat s$ can be pulled out of the differential as it is constant and you are left with an equations which links components in a particular direction $\hat s$ which might be $\hat x$, $\hat i$, etc.

[image]

Using the two equations the other two equations $s=v_{\rm i}t+\frac 12 at^2$ and $v_{\rm f}^2 = v_{\rm i}^2+2as$ can be derived.

*. . . . . but in circular motion the [**linear**] acceleration is not constant as the direction is always changing.*
I have added an important word to your statement and note that the kinematic equations you are asking about are for rotations at constant **angular** acceleration, $\hat \alpha $ about a fixed axis (equivalent to the  fixed direction $\hat s$ for linear motion).
The direction is usually assigned by using the [right hand grip rule](https://web.ua.es/docivis/magnet/righthand_rule.html) and in the end you get an equivalent set of equations which relate the components of angle, angular velocity, angular acceleration and time.

[image]

If you now consider circular motion about a fixed axis relative to the plane defined by the circle you can use the kinematic equations for constant angular acceleration just as you use those for constant linear acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the amount a thing rotates, starting at some initial rotation $\theta'$ and initial angular velocity $\dot{\theta}$ and rotating with constant acceleration $\ddot{\theta}$, then you can use the formula

$\theta=\theta' + \dot{\theta} t + \frac{1}{2} \ddot{\theta}t^2 $.

Recall the definition of $\theta$ in radians.

$\theta= \frac{\text{arc length}}{R}$ where $R$ is constant.

Then $\text{arclength} = \text{arc length}' + \frac{d\text{(arc length)}}{dt} t +\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2\text{ (arc length)}}{dt^2} t^2$.

(Divide by $R$ to get $\theta=\theta' + \dot{\theta} t + \frac{1}{2} \ddot{\theta}t^2 $.)

The arc length is the initial arc length plus a term due to the initial velocity of arc length plus a term due to the acceleration of the arc length.

You can verify that this works by taking derivatives.

Note that arc length is just a number. It doesn't have direction or curvature.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but are we not going to treat them as vectors then? Cause don't I need to take into account centripetal acceleration and tangential acceleration?

Comment: @mach123 not necessarily. it depends on the problem. the key thing here is that arc length is only a number. so i can use this math to find how much an object has rotated. if that's what i'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about physics for a minute. The kinematic equations are derived from calculus when the second derivative of a quantity $y(x)$ is constant.

$$\begin{gathered}
 y''  = A \\
 y'  = \int y'' {\rm d}x = A x + B \\
 y  = \int y' {\rm d}x = \tfrac{1}{2} A x^2 + B x + C
\end{gathered} $$

and you can combine the 2nd and 3rd equation to get $$ y = \frac{y'^2 - B^2}{2 A} + C$$

The application of the above equations is for any physical system whose 2nd derivative is constant.

This might be linear displacement $x$, whose second derivative $a$ is acceleration as you know them
$$\begin{gathered}
 a =  A \\
 v =  \int a {\rm d}t = A t + B \\
 x =  \int v {\rm d}t = \tfrac{1}{2} A t^2 + B t + C
\end{gathered} $$

or angular displacement $\theta$, whose second derivative $\alpha$ is rotational acceleration

$$\begin{gathered}
 \alpha =  A \\
 \omega =  \int \alpha {\rm d}t = A t + B \\
 \theta =  \int \omega {\rm d}t = \tfrac{1}{2} A t^2 + B t + C
\end{gathered} $$

Same exact equation, but the names of the variables differ.

So for *any* quantity (scalar or vector) whose 2nd derivative is constant the above equations hold regardless of the type of quantity used. The requirement is that $y'' = \text{<const>}$.

---

The reason these equations are called the kinematics equations is that they represent relationships between motion quantities without consideration of actual forces. All of the above expressions are a consequence of a single kinematics expression of the form $y'' = \text{<const>}$.

Another example of kinematics expressions is a rolling ball of radius $r$ without slipping. The velocity of the center $v$ and the rotational speed $\omega$ are related with the following kinematic equation

$$ v +\omega r  = 0 $$

if which we can differentiate and integral to get the following supporting functions

$$ \begin{gathered}
 a + \alpha r  = 0 \\
 x + \theta r = 0 
\end{gathered}$$

To solve problems in mechanics, first, you need to establish the kinematics of the situation, where your motion variables are related to each other to conform to contacts, joints, and other mechanical constraints. Then the equations of motion can be applied to see how these motion variables change over time.

Answer (score 0):

(1) dω/dt = α  ( angular acceleration )

Therefore :

$ ω_f = ω_i + αt $

(2) Conservation of energy

$ 1/2Iω_f^2 -1/2Iω_i^2 = Tθ $

T is the applied torque = Iα  ; I is the moment of interia of the rotating object

Therefore :

$ ω_f^2 = ω_i^2 + 2αθ $

(3) from (1)

$ d θ / dt = ω = ω_i + αt $

Therefore

$ θ = ω_it + 1/2 αt^2 $